# Django - Access and save files to remote server

Tags: django, nginx, file-upload

I am currently developping an application using Django.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have a remote server that will host configuration files. Those files are going to be numerous but quite small. 
The configuration of my server is the following : on the adress 172.x.x.51 I have my Django app running with uwsgi and on 172.x.x.52 I have my nginx service connected to my uwsgi instance.

What I would like is to host the files on the nginx server. 
Inside the application, I will need to access to the files and to save them (they are calculated from data from the database, so there's no need for a fileupload).

I looked on the documentation and found that I can use a Custom Storage System. The thing is, I don't think that's what I need because I want to store them the way it's done by default. I would just like to define the place where the files should be updated from Django.

Would it be better if I stored them in the media folder on my nginx instance ? How would I say to Django to go look on nginx's instance for the files ? On the server where nginx is hosted, I already host my static files and it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a question about Django really. Storage backends are for file uploads, but as you say you're not doing that.

You need some way of allowing your Django instance on *.51 write to your nginx server on *.52. This might be via SSH/SCP, or by sharing directories over NFS, for example. Then you can simply save the files over that protocol to the relevant place, from where nginx can serve them.